# Capacitor doesn't work for Ionic with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

When creating Ionic app following documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/quickstart and converting typescript to javascript (10 steps on this doc page), then there is a problem creating android version by running this command: `ionic cap add android`

This command should create `android` folder, but i get this error message:

[image]

This error doesn't exist if application is set for typescript, it appears only after converting to javascript.

Seems this is an internal issue with capacitor. Is there a way to fix this via vite.config or something similar?

By the way it's Ionic version 7

Answer (score 0):

I found in documentation of Capacitor that if you don't use typescript, you should use `.json` for config file. The documentation of Ionic misleads as it states all `.ts` file should be converted to `.js` files.